# How many alarms can be set on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, alarm

How many alarms can be set on an iPhone 5? Can you set one for every minute of the day (1440) or is there a limit on the number of alarms?

Answer (score 6):

Well if we want to be 100% accurate, there is a limit. It is the storage capacity of your iPhone 5s. Somewhere that alarm is taking up space and once it runs out, so do the alarms.

I've just tapped the '+' followed by "Save" and got up to over 300 alarms before I realized how much fun I'll have going back and deleting them all. Or,  since their default value after creation is set to "on", absolutely drive people crazy at work tomorrow.

Also, since it only took 5 minutes, it is a dang good prank to play on a friend - or enemy :)

So, realistically grgarside is right. There is not limit set via programming; however, like I mentioned, the storage capacity is the true cap - eventually at least.

Comment: "Switch off all my alarms" works with Siri :)

Comment: @AdityaMP Wow way to ruin the prank :)

Answer (score 4):

There is basically no limit. You can set one for every minute of the day, or even more than one for every minute.

Comment: Really? Can you proof that?

Comment: @wumm It uses a local database. You can have as many as you want until you run out of disk space on your iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

Every minute; 1,440 (24 hours* 60 minutes) then add the possibilities for days (i.e Mondays and Tuesdays, every Wednesday etc.) which is 2 (1 for not that day as a possibility and 1 for that day being a possibility; so 2) to the power of how many days you can set (7) gives us 2^7 or 2*2*2*2*2*2*2 which is 128.

So if we combine those two together (128*1,440) we get 184,320 different possible alarms. If your phone could store all these, I'm not certain, but in theory that's the max amount of different alarms.

If we include text descriptions then the number would be such a great amount that no device could ever display it (as we have to take into consideration how many possibilities there are; just two letters in a row with the english alphabet (26 letters), that would be 26*26 (676) without symbols like periods or commas, and without the possibility of different sizes of letters (lower/uppercase).

If an alarm text description could include 20 letters, that can ONLY be letters which are either upper or lowercase, and NO symbols, that would be 26^20 (thats 26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26*26), and that number would equal 19,928,148,895,209,409,152,340,197,376.

**TL;DR:**

So anyway, 184,320 different possible alarms if you exclude counting different text descriptions, like a sane person. Or a much, much bigger number if you do. Either way your phone probably cannot store that many alarms, so realistically it's probably in the thousands somewhere.

Comment: Aside, the average english speaker knows how to use around 20,000 words. We can cut this down to around 5,000 words likely to be used in a reminder message because people generally try to keep their reminders short and only use long words as the entire reminder like incomprehensible, hypothetically, inconsequential,  etc. Then every other word is usually one of about 100 different words used for structure: to, the, of, when, that, is, etc. So, the *likely possible* up to three word reminders (minus proper names) are only: 20000 + 100*20000 + 100*5000 + 5000*5000 + 5000*100*5000 + 100*5000*5000